# Construct and use Scanner in Java

Tags: java, file-io, constructor, io

I am looking at examples using `Scanner` to read a file (in Java). In one example, the `Scanner` was constructed using:

```
s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))
```

But in another example the code is like below. My question is that is there something wrong with the way `Scanner` was declared below? Do we not need to use the  `s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))` constructor?

```
int howMany;
Scanner scan = null;
File f;
String[] words = null;

try {
    f = new File(filename);
    scan= new Scanner(f);
    howMany = scan.nextInt();
    words = new String[howMany];

    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
        words[i] = scan.next();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Check the documentation - Scanner has several overloaded constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple valid ways to construct a `Scanner`. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to see all of them.

There is nothing wrong with the approach that you have shown in your question.